# How do I parse dates with more than 24 hours in dateutil's parser in Python 3?

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, python-3.x

I currently have a bunch of times in a column written like "27:32:18", meaning someone was waiting for 27 hours, 32 minutes, and 18 seconds.  I keep getting "ValueError: hour must be in 0..23" whenever I try to parse these values.

How should I go about parsing those values or converting them to a more standard format?  I tried the following as a test on a single value:

```
time1 = "56:42:12"
time2 = time1.split(':')
time2 = [int(n) for n in time2]
time2.insert(0, time2[0] // 24)
time2[1] %= 24
```

At that point, time2 is a list consisting of [2, 8, 42, 12], which is equivalent to 2 days, 8 hours, 42 minutes, and 12 seconds.  How would I go about converting that to a Python datetime representation in days, hours, minutes, and seconds in a way that will allow Python to parse it?  Note that I will eventually be doing unsupervised clustering on these time values, which represent waiting times.

Comment: That is *not a date*. A *time duration* is a different beast altogether.

Comment: A python datetime object can only be used to represent a specific point in time; e.g. the 31st of July 1889. Durations are expressed in `timedelta()` objects.

Comment: An interval needs to have a reference from which it is a delta. Just saying "2 days, 8 hours, 42 minutes" without specifying the _since_ part, will make the _date_ part difficult. If you just want to calculate time durations, this (like Martijn said), is another thing.

Comment: Thank you!  So work with timedeltas instead of datetimes.

Answer (score 11):

You don't *have* a date, you have a time duration. That may be related to dates and timestamps, but only in that the same units of time are involved and are displayed similarly to timestamps.

As such, you cannot use `dateutil` for parsing such values. It is easy enough to split out and parse yourself:

```
hours, minutes, seconds = map(int, time1.split(':'))
```

You can then use a `datetime.timedelta()` object to represent the duration:

```
td = datetime.timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)
```

This'll then track the delta in terms of days, seconds and microseconds:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> time1 = "56:42:12"
>>> hours, minutes, seconds = map(int, time1.split(':'))
>>> datetime.timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)
datetime.timedelta(2, 31332)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Although for whatever reason it's not letting me actually change the stored values.  I have the following for loop.  Please note that it's Pandas code:

for time in df.elapsed_time:
    hours, minutes, seconds = map(int, time.split(':'))
    time = timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)

Comment: Why do you need to change the stored values? What values are you trying to change?

Comment: I need to change the stored values so I can do data analysis on waiting times for patients in an emergency room.  There is other pertinent patient information so I need the updated values to be in the large data frame I am working with.  I am trying to convert values stored like "54:23:45" to timedeltas like (2, 31332) so I can eventually do some clustering in scikit-learn.

Comment: Hi @BrandonSherman you can use `df['elapsed_time_new'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.elapsed_time)` to create a new column in your `DataFrame` that will contain `timedelta` objects that you can manipulate as you need for your analysis. The documentation for `to_timedelta` can be found [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html). Note that these objects are broken down into days, hours, minutes, seconds so you may need some further work to break it down into (days, seconds) which is what you seem to want.

Comment: Thanks!  But sadly I'm stuck with Pandas 0.12 because my workplace uses Pyzo.  It doesn't have the to_timedelta method and I have no way of upgrading to another version of Pandas.  How would I manually do that?

Comment: That's really unfortunate :( what you can do instead then is write a function (let's call it `convert` to keep it short) which takes one of your strings and then converts it and returns a `timedelta` object then you can do `df['elapsed_time_new'] = df['elapsed_time'].apply(convert)` and it will apply your `convert` function to each string in your column and place it in your new column. You can probably use the method that Martijn has given in his answer above to write such a function.