# how to convert time in which hr value is greater than 24?

Tags: python, python-3.x

this how my dataset looks like ;-

Timestamp

- 2020-11-1 0:1:28:11265
- 2020-11-1 0:2:3:38616
- 2020-11-1 0:3:30:31943
- 2020-11-1 0:4:25:2289
- 2020-11-1 0:5:4:45378

I try to convert above timestamp using below functions

```
import datetime 
def convert(date_time): 
    format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f' # The format 
    datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time, format)
    datetime_str = datetime_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

df['Timestamp'] = df['Timestamp'].apply(convert)
df.head()
```

after running above code i get below error.

```
ValueError: time data '2020-11-1 24:0:47:40476' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f'
```

how do i convert the date '2020-11-1 24:0:47:40476' --> '2020-11-2 0:0:47:40476'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse dates with more than 24 hours in dateutil's parser in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24432607/how-do-i-parse-dates-with-more-than-24-hours-in-dateutils-parser-in-python-3)

Comment: BTW, why on earth do you `strptime`, and then `strftime`, and then `strptime` again?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the date and time separately, parsing the date part into just a date with the time component set to 0:00:00, then add the time part as `timedelta` to it:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> s = '2020-11-1 24:0:47:40476'
>>> d, t = s.split()
>>> d
'2020-11-1'
>>> t
'24:0:47:40476'
>>> ts = datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> ts
datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 1, 0, 0)
>>> h, m, s, ms = t.split(':')
>>> ts + timedelta(hours=int(h), minutes=int(m), seconds=int(s), milliseconds=int(ms))
datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 2, 0, 1, 27, 476000)
```

Note that this may or may not work as desired should DST transitions happen right during that time; it's a bit unclear how that's *supposed* to work.

Also note that the 40476 milliseconds (?) added up to additional minutes. It’s slightly unclear what exactly that number is supposed to represent, you may have to split that up into milli- and microseconds too before passing it to `timedelta`.